# reading value from an RDF file in java

Tags: java, rdf

The following is my RDF file structure.

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.wordpress.com/blogs/ckj">
    <rdf:subject>Data structures</rdf:subject>
    <rdf:object>vijayalakshmi</rdf:object>
    <rdf:value>kjhjk</rdf:value>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I want to write a piece of java code that can 
       -->  read the value of   into a model inside a java program.

How should I do this??

I am a newbie. So, please help!!

Comment: I'm not sure, but this should be parseable by a STAX parser. A good reference for this is at http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaXML/article.html#javastax

Comment: The above comment is unfounded. Do not use XML parsers to parse RDF/XML. Use an RDF Parser (that may internally use an XML parser)

Comment: Same question posted on jena-users: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-jena-users/201203.mbox/%3CCAEUzCGA7ZXyMyL_WZz9fgGyiynPPgnsWwCfLrbPaBFX4%3DmUufw%40mail.gmail.com%3E (the thread includes answers).

Answer (score 1):

1. You should have a look at a well known API to process RDF from Java: [Jena](http://incubator.apache.org/jena/%20Jena)
2. Your sample seems not valid. You are trying to describe a resource (http://incubator.apache.org/jena/) with three statements that are not designed to.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on @ymomb answer, the RDF resource you have created is conceptually not very sound. You are using terms from the core RDF vocabulary in ways not intended (you should not use a literal as the range of a rdf:subject). Its a little bit difficult to re-represent your resource since a couple of statements include gibberish, but something like the following would be more appropriate:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"> 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.wordpress.com/blogs/ckj">
    <rdfs:label>Data structures</rdfs:label>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

To use this in Java, again, as recommended by @ymomb , you can use Jena.

```
Model rdfModel = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel().read("url-of-rdf-resource.rdf");
```